# How can I mimic user operation while machine is locked

Tags: java, automation

I have created a program in java which will emulate user activity in windows operating system (like clicking left mouse button), but as soon as I lock my system the activity also stops.

Is there any way to keep it running.

Let me know if any more details are required....

Comment: how are you emulating the user? What approach/winodws APIs are you using?

Comment: How are you emulating user activity? What type of "user activity" are to creating?

Answer (score 0):

If it's browser based activity, try Selenium, which you can use to send mouse clicks, and many other events to a browser.
[Link to Selenium site](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

A good scripting language to automate (emulate) all kinds of windows tasks is AutoIT.
It's comes with good documentation & is easy to learn!

Download:
http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml